# Python Unicode Errors, sync up the dev environment and production

Tags: python, development-environment, production-environment, python-unicode

I've just run into a few unicode errors with a application I'm running, that every now and again has to deal with really odd strings, most recently,

```
Pınar Karsıyaka
```

in my dev environment (Aptana w. PyDev on Mavericks Mac with an up to date homebrew python install), dealing with this string doesn't produce an error, and is printed to the console as

```
P\u0131nar Kars\u0131yaka v Torku Selcuk
```

but on the production environment, standard Ubuntu and Python install on an Amazon EC2 small box, this is printed like

```
P\xc4\xb1nar Kars\xc4\xb1yaka v Torku Selcuk
```

and gives one of the dreaded Python errors,

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0131' in position 50: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I would like to know how (if possible) to enable the prod environment to be able to deal with these characters, like my dev environment can, but also would like to be able to change my dev environment to break like the prod one, so that I can handle the occurrences where this happens within the code.

Thanks for any help in regards this.

Mac Python -
 Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  1 2013, 18:38:34)
 [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin

Ubuntu Python -
 Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15)
 [GCC 4.6.3] on linux2

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Probably the shell encoding on the server is not UTF-8 but yours is at home. Compare the value of, say, `echo $LC_ALL` on each.

Comment: Python 2.7 on each, added the full details to the question.  @Two-BitAlchemist, that's showing up as blank / empty on both machines for me.

Comment: @seaders OK, how about `$LANG` or `$LC_CTYPE`? Also, are you running the Mac Terminal program at home but accessing your EC2 box with something like ssh?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, $LC_TYPE is again blank in both, $LANG is en_IE.UTF-8 in dev, en_US.UTF-8 on the Amazon box. On the EC2 box, yeah, sshing, locally, I'm running the commands you're asking about in iTerm, but all the other Python code in Aptana.

Comment: @seaders OK, you're set for UTF-8 on both. Maybe the file encoding is ASCII in one place and UTF-8 in another? In Python 2.7, don't you have to set `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file? IIRC, UTF-8 became default in Py3K. Have you done this on the files at least on your EC2 box? (Better if it's in both places.)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, thanks for all this help, but just tried that in the offending file, and the entry point to the app and still no luck.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of the exception? That will help narrow down what operation is causing your `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Comment: add   # coding: utf8   at the first line and tell us the result

Answer (score 3):

If you dive a little in the 2.7 branch of the python sources, you will find out that the [default encoding of unicode strings](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d1a641ecbe33/Python/sysmodule.c#l229) is firstly [set to some forced value](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d1a641ecbe33/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l1421) (now, it is "ascii", though it has been "utf-8" before then), but it is [overridden by the site module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d1a641ecbe33/Lib/site.py#l538) during each instantiation of the interpreter.

To check the behaviour on each platform, run :

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.getdefaultencoding())'
```

Now, if you want to make them even, it is not really simple, because the function
'setdefaultencoding' is [deleted in the site module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d1a641ecbe33/Lib/site.py#l546), so that you have to
reload the sys module to get it :

```
$ python -c 'import sys; reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8"); print(sys.getdefaultencoding())'
```

That way, you can have the same encoding, *in your interpreter*, on each platform regardless of the locales and
encoding defined at multiple levels from the os to the python build.

Answer (score 1):

**Library versions**

Please verify that all the library versions are the same, I suspect that there's an API change that returns `unicode` vs `str` from some external data source. I've seen these issues before when upgrading `SQLObject` and `Cherrypy`. Also data source settings are important, for example if you use a `mysql` server, you need to pay attention to `default_encoding`.

Your questions does not specify data source, it's hard to guess.

At the very least, do `pip freeze` in both enrivonments and compare the version numbers.

**Default encoding**

Check if there is `sitecustomize.py` in one of the environments -- that's the official way to set up any wonky things (which you shouldn't anyway, but that's another story).

It probably does exactly what @chocko01 suggests -- sets deafault encoding. Check it by logging `sys.getdefaultencoding()` in both environments.

Setting default encoding in Python makes conversion `unicode<->str` (Python2) and `str<->bytes` (Python3) transparent, but in the long run it's a bad idea. Remember that `explicit is better than implicit`.

**Trace your data**

it's a tough [CCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) to crack, but unless you can capture this particular problem in a reproducible test, the 2nd best is to dump tons of logs and then work your way backwards and see where your funky input comes from.

Then trace it downwards to determine where the difference is between your local and production environments.

At the point of error, it's `unicode` in your local env and `UTF-8` encoded, aka `str` in production env. The fact that you have a sample for both environments suggests that you are able to reproduce the problem. Perhaps you should write an automated test as well.

Comment: this isn't an answer and should instead have been a comment to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23319208/247648

Comment: expanded; btw @Giel if we are going to be pedantic, your link point to my answer and not the question.

Comment: no it points to choko01's answer, and I see you've completely rewritten your answer, so I'll un-downvote this

Comment: ahh, sorry, that's the problem of having a very large display -- html anchors are hard to interpret :)